# Android.mk copy a bin to /system/xbin

Tags: android, android.mk

like this Android.mk can copy **123.bin** into **/system/bin** .

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
$(call add-prebuilt-files, EXECUTABLES, 123.bin)
```

but i want to copy 123.bin into **/system/xbin**, how can i do it. i know this:

```
               will copy to
ETC                ====>    /system/etc
EXECUTABLES        ====>    /system/bin
SHARED_LIBRARIES   ====>    /system/lib
STATIC_LIBRARIES   ====>    /system/lib
```

Comment: Why not look through the source for the handling of the tools which already end up in that directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := 123.bin
LOCAL_MODULE_PATH := $(TARGET_OUT)/xbin
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := 123.bin
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := EXECUTABLE
include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)
```

Answer (score 0):

don't use

```
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := OPTIONAL_EXECUTABLES
LOCAL_MODULE_PATH := $(TARGET_OUT)/xbin
```

but just

```
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := OPTIONAL_EXECUTABLES
```

which is formally better. See [core/envsetup.mk](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/+/master/core/envsetup.mk#652)

Answer (score 0):

You should try this

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := 123.bin
LOCAL_MODULE_PATH := $(PRODUCT_OUT)/system/xbin   ---> INFO : Just mention the path where you want your app, xml, exec etc
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := 123.bin
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := EXECUTABLE
include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)
```